# Does this complex integral transform have a name?

Tags: complex-analysis, integral-transforms

We are all familiar with the Stieltjes transform of a real function of bounded variation $F$, which is defined as follows (up to some sign convention that varies across authors):
$$\forall z\in\mathbb{C}^+\qquad s_F(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x-z}dF(x)~.$$
My question is whether there is a name for the closely related transformation:
$$\forall z\in\mathbb{C}^+\qquad m_F(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x}{x-z}dF(x)~.$$
Technically, we could call it "the Stieltjes transform of the incomplete moment function of order one", but that's a bit of a mouthful. The two transforms are related by the equation:
$$\forall z\in\mathbb{C}^+\qquad m_F(z)=1+z\,s_F(z)~.$$
I tried to look up the *Generalized* Stieltjes transform, but it came out as something completely different, namely:
$$\forall z\in\mathbb{C}^+\qquad s_F^\rho(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(x-z)^\rho}dF(x)\quad\text{for some index }\rho>0~.$$

Comment: what in particular would the kernel $x/(x-z)$ buy you? If it is so closely related to the ordinary transform, it probably is not different enough analytically to bother giving it its own name.

Comment: If $F = G\,'$ then $m_F(z) = s_{x F}(z)-s_G(z)$

Comment: To ALB: for me, F is the cumulative distribution function of a distribution with support in the positive half of the real line. The zero does not behave like other numbers because there are scaling effects. So all the equations become simpler by using the kernel $x/(x-z)$. Also, if I go to numerical work, I don't get densities blowing up to infinity in the vicinity of zero.

Comment: To user1952009: As I said in my answer to ALB's comment, for me $F$ is a c.d.f., so it is not the derivative of anything. It may not even be continuous, so I would not be able to use the identity that you propose.